# Brackets Live Preview Error " Page is not part of the current project"

Tags: html, localhost, mamp, code-editor, htdocs

My Document root on MAMP is C:\MAMP\htdocs

The Live Preview base URL is https://localhost/

Live preview was definitely working before when I just clicked "File"-->"Open.." and selected an html file, but now that I click on "File"-->"Open Folder" chose htdocs and clicked on the same html file, the message on Brackets reads "Live preview was cancelled because the browser navigated to a page that is not part of the current project." Google Chrome just says "localhost refused to connect." I tried opening a new file and tried Live Preview, but the same thing happens. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Live Preview was definitely working before I opened a folder...[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I just grouped all my html files into a folder, clicked "file-->open folder" and selected the folder with all the html, css, and images inside, then clicked on one of my html files and Live Preview works just fine. Didn't understand how this whole project thing works but now I do.